# PyQt4 Can I preview a plot before closing window?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt4

My program asks for various inputs and saves a corresponding plot for the user. I'd like to be able to have a "Preview" option where if they press "Preview", it implements the options and they can see the plot before they hit a "Done" button that generates the .jpg they request. Ideally, I want them to be able to hit "Preview", make adjustments to the inputs, and hit "Preview" again to see if that's how they want it to look.

I added a "Preview" button, and it didn't seem to work - then I closed the Main Window and it did show the plot.

Here's the code for my "Preview" and "Done" buttons:

```
def preview(self):
    self.final = False
    self.id = str(self.identifier_ask.text())
    self.limits = [float(self.vel_low_ask.text()), float(self.vel_high_ask.text())]
    if self.flip_bool_ask.isChecked():
        self.flip = True
    else:
        self.flip = False


def finish_input_click(self):
    self.final = True
    self.id = str(self.identifier_ask.text())
    self.limits = [float(self.vel_low_ask.text()), float(self.vel_high_ask.text())]
    if self.flip_bool_ask.isChecked():
        self.flip = True
    else:
        self.flip = False

    self.close()
```

And here's the code in my plotting function:

```
if cw.final:
    figure_path = pathname + 'velocity ' + cw.id + '.jpg'
    fig.savefig(figure_path, dpi = 200)
    plt.close()
else:
    plt.show()
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I want without basically duplicating my plotting function inside the compiled window class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "preview" code you are not calling the plot into view (it seems), just giving a flag to your class. So I'm guessing that when you close your window you call the plot function and the flag says it should give a plot.

Since you are using the matplotlib I would advise you to make a second instance of the plot so that once the user closes it you won't loose the information you have set before. So in the preview function you should also make a plot (like a copy of the one you're doing in your software).

Comment: How would I implement the plot before closing the window?

Comment: @mauve How are you doing it now? Let's say you are saving somewhere the arguments for a plot (marker, linestyle,x,y, etc.). From this you can build a matplotlib plot on request using a figure [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multiple_figs_demo.html). Edit your post to show your plot code if you are still in doubt.

Comment: My problem is in calling the function from the active window....right now, when I hit "Preview" nothing happens...*until* I close the QMainWindow. Then the plot shows just fine. My question is about how to get it to show *when I hit the Preview button* instead of after that window is closed.

Comment: By putting plt.show() inside your "preview" function. As I said you are not calling anything plot related in the function you have put in your post.

Comment: So I have to move the plotting stuff inside the QMainWindow() class, and there's no other way.

Comment: Yes there is. The problem is that you are not calling a plot (or a function that does a plot, or a function that calls a function that does a plot) in "preview". Look at the function you wrote. Do you see any instruction there that should create a plot?